# How to filter out multiple results based on some condition from structures stored in a file?

Tags: c, file, struct

This is my first struct:

```
struct candidate
{
    char fullName[50];
    char email[50];
    char division[20];
    int age;
    int voter_num;
    char citizenship_no[15];
    char district[20];
    char party[20];
    char post[20];
    char sex;
    int province_num;
};
```

and this is the second struct:

```
struct votes
{
    int voter_num;
    int total_votes;
};
```

I want to fetch out all such candidates whose `voter_num` **is  equal to** that of `voter_num` of `votes` struct:
I tried this way:

```
struct candidate candi;
cfp = fopen("Candidates.dat", "rb+");
vfp = fopen("Votes.dat", "rb+");
rewind(vfp);
struct votes display_votes;

while (fread(&candi, sizeof(struct candidate), 1, cfp))
{
  
    while (fread(&display_votes, sizeof(struct votes), 1, vfp))
//if i print out candidates here i get proper results
                            {
                                
                                if (candi.voter_num == display_votes.voter_num)
                                {
//but not here , only first satisfied candidate

printf("-----------");
                                printf("\n|District:-%s\t\t Province Number:%d", candi.district, candi.province_num);
                                printf("\n-----------\n\n");
                                printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                                printf("Voter-Num\tCandidate\t\tParty\t\tPost\t\tTotal-Votes\n");
                                printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                                printf("%d%18s%22s%18s%15d", display_votes.voter_num, candi.fullName, candi.party, candi.post, display_votes.total_votes);
}
}
}
```

And closed both file here:) but it gives out first matced result only not others,**help me out please?**

Comment: You read each file exactly once. After the inner loop ended, you will not get any new data for second iteration of outer loop. You probably need to move the `rewind(vfp);` after the inner `while` loop. And there is no `fp` to rewind...

Comment: Your problem description suggest you are using arrays of `struct`.  But you show no arrays in the posted code.  Please provide enough of you code here to show what you have tried, and where it failed to do what you intended, and that it be [mcve]

Comment: As you use `fread` to read structs, you should open yor files in binary mode.

Comment: @Gerhardh - I think both of us are victims of assuming some things.  Me assuming OP is using arrays of struct in which to populate from a csv, or similar, You, assuming the data is in binary just because `fread` is used.   Neither is clearly evident in OP's description :)  This is a good candidate for getting more clarification from OP

Comment: @ryyker True. ;) On the other hand the OP complains about printing too little data, not about printing wrong data. Therefore the `fread` seems to read proper content which can only be true for binary data. ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh there is fp file too which i didn't post here as it don't have anything to do here so and movind rewind(vfp) after inner while loop didn't work

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also provide content of your files together with output and expected output.

Comment: @Gerhardh i m posting main core problem ,

Comment: can u just tell me that how i can get out all such candidates if a given condition satisfy from a votes struct?

Comment: Without knowing your file content and expected output, i would do a wild guess that you might switch the inner and outer loop. But if that does not help, we need more context as was requested twice already.

Comment: @Gerhardh i have edited post ,please go through post once  again from first and let me know if u don't understand anythingelse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246738/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-gunaraj-khatri).

Comment: i have sent txt

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, you need to use `rewind` on `vfp` in the outer loop.

First I made a simple program to generate test data.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct candidate
{
    char fullName[50];
    char email[50];
    char division[20];
    int age;
    int voter_num;
    char citizenship_no[15];
    char district[20];
    char party[20];
    char post[20];
    char sex;
    int province_num;
};

struct votes
{
    int voter_num;
    int total_votes;
};

struct candidate candidates[] = {
    // Fullname    email                 div   age v#   c#      district party   post     G    PN
    { "John Doe", "johndoe@noreply.com", "TP", 25, 100, "Five", "South", "Whig", "12345", 'M', 1 },
    { "Jane Doe", "janedoe@noreply.com", "JP", 29, 50,  "Six",  "North", "Tea",  "54321", 'F', 2 },
    { "Jodi Doe", "jodidoe@noreply.com", "JP", 31, 100, "Six",  "West",  "Jam",  "12345", 'F', 3 },
};

struct votes votess[] = {
    // v# total
    { 100, 200},
    { 200, 300},
    { 100, 400},
    { 100, 500},
};

int main()
{
    FILE *cfp = fopen("Candidates.dat", "wb+");
    FILE *vfp = fopen("Votes.dat", "wb+");

    if (!cfp || !vfp) {
        printf("One or more files could not be opened\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fwrite(candidates, sizeof(candidates[0]), sizeof(candidates) / sizeof(candidates[0]), cfp);
    fwrite(votess, sizeof(votess[0]), sizeof(votess) / sizeof(votess[0]), vfp);

    fclose(vfp);
    fclose(cfp);

    return 0;
}
```

After generating the files, I slightly modified your program and added the `rewind` with the following result that seems to work:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct candidate
{
    char fullName[50];
    char email[50];
    char division[20];
    int age;
    int voter_num;
    char citizenship_no[15];
    char district[20];
    char party[20];
    char post[20];
    char sex;
    int province_num;
};

struct votes
{
    int voter_num;
    int total_votes;
};

int main()
{
    struct candidate candi;
    FILE *cfp = fopen("Candidates.dat", "rb+");
    FILE *vfp = fopen("Votes.dat", "rb+");
    struct votes display_votes;

    if (!cfp || !vfp) {
        printf("One or more files could not be opened\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fread(&candi, sizeof(struct candidate), 1, cfp))
    {
        while (fread(&display_votes, sizeof(struct votes), 1, vfp))
        {
            if (candi.voter_num == display_votes.voter_num)
            {
                printf("-----------");
                printf("\n|District:-%s\t\t Province Number:%d", candi.district, candi.province_num);
                printf("\n-----------\n");
                printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("Voter-Num\tCandidate\t\tParty\t\tPost\t\tTotal-Votes\n");
                printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("%d%18s%22s%18s%15d\n\n", display_votes.voter_num, candi.fullName, candi.party, candi.post, display_votes.total_votes);
            }
        }
        rewind(vfp);
    }
    fclose(vfp);
    fclose(cfp);

    return 0;
}
```